# SOAMANAGER can not be displayed

Tags: abap, trial, sap-basis

as the topic suggests I can not access the SOAMANAGER transaction, and after days of gooling I am at my wits end.

My environment:
- SAP NetWeaver 7.50 SP1 AS ABAP and SAP BW on SAP HANA [Developer Edition],
From http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-41566 .

My attempts:

- I have activated: default_host/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/APPL_SOAP_MANAGEMENT
- Attempted to access the SOAMANAGER with "developer" and "DDIC"

The link it tries to open:
http://vhcala4hci.wdf.sap.corp:50000/sap/public/myssocntl?sap-client=001

Aside the problem that the APPL_SOAP_MANAGEMENT or the port is 0 I could not get any other problems/solutions on google. I hope someone can help.

UPDATE: 
SE93 -> SOAMANAGER 
[image]

If I go to SICF... Services, find the  the APPL_SOAP_MANAGEMENT, do right click, and test service i get the following link:

http://vhcala4hci.wdf.sap.corp:50000/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/appl_soap_management?sap-client=001

Though it has the same effect "Server not found". I have also attempted replacing the adress with the IP, but cane to the same result.... "Server not found".

Comment: And what is the http error you're getting?

Comment: Server not found.

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of the transaction `SE93` for `SOAMANAGER`? The link it tries to open is completely wrong as there should be `/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/appl_soap_management` after the server name. The only thing that comes to my mind is that someone modified this standard transaction in the system.

Comment: Just edited the post to show the picture...

Comment: Try changing the port from 50000 to 8000.

Comment: Port 8000 isnt active, 50000 and 50001 are active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adding domain to your host file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

sapserverip  vhcala4hci.wdf.sap.corp

Comment: I tried substituting the vhcala4hci.wdf.sap.corp with the servers IP (in the link) but it did not change anything, so I guess that adding the link to hosts will not make any difference?

Comment: @stackmonkey sap server cannot response incoming requests which are coming from IP. You need to make request with domain name.

Comment: Yea that did it. Thank you.